# What does this notation mean for a squared matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a square matrix

$A^n = A \cdot A\cdot$...$n$ times

What's $A^{2n}$?

$2A^n$ or $A \cdot A\cdot$...$2n$ times?

Comment: it's the product $2n$ times

Comment: The exponential notation for matrices is meant to harmonize with regular notation for real numbers.  When would you ever interpret $x^{2n}$ as $2x^n$?  Was there some other instance of similar notation that you saw which led you to believe this?  Maybe you should ask about that instead :)

Comment: Just take n = 2k in the first equation. Then you directly see that A^{2k} = A \cdot A \cdot... A 2k times.

Comment: As S.Farr says: Since you know what $A^n$ is, write $n=2m$, so that you have $A^{2m}$, which you already now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means $A\cdot A\cdot \dotsb$ $2n$ times, it's just a convenient way of making it clear that the power is even.